# Convert file upload to multiple file upload c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Hello I'm trying to create a multiple file upload with C#, at the moment I can upload only one but I need to upload more than one, another thing is that I have to show a preview of the file (only images), I have code for a multiple file upload but only works in framework 4+ and my app is in 3.5, I'm thinking about using a foreach or something like that but I'm not sure so I hope you can help me, here is my C# method for file upload:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile && this.alertatxt.Text != "" && this.pietxt.Text != "")
        {
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".png" || extension == ".jpeg")
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
                int alerta = Convert.ToInt32(this.alertatxt.Text);
                string pie = this.pietxt.Text;
                using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
                {
                    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
                        {
                            string query = "INSERT INTO foto(FileName, ContentType, Content, IdAlerta, PieFoto) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content, @alerta, @pie)";
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                            {
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alerta", alerta);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pie", pie);
                                con.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con.Close();
                            }
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Uploaded.');", true);
                        }

                    }
                    this.pietxt.Text = "";
                }
            }
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('File must be .jpg . png .jpeg');", true);
            this.pietxt.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Fill all the fields.');", true);
            this.alertatxt.Focus();
            this.pietxt.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:** Image preview is not much important but however here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center form-group">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" />
                                </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center form-group">
                                <img id="img" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width: 300px" />
                            </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showimagepreview(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {

                document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `AllowMultiple` property was only added to the FileUpload control in .Net 4.0, this means you are going to have to do some heavy lifting yourself.

If you have a small fixed maximum amount of uploads, for instance 3, you could simply add 3 FileUpload controls to the page and loop over `Request.Files`.

If you have large maximum limit, it might be better to add upload fields dynamically using javascript and loop over `Request.Files` property in the page code.

There are examples of doing exactly this:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/multiple-file-upload-using-jquery-in-asp-net-3-5/

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-FileUpload-Control-in-ASPNet-20-30-and-35.aspx

Comment: I'm going to check that information also I'm thinking about using a generic handler, thanks bro.